Unable to translate languages ​in Flutter
I am using easy_localization in my application. I changed the language setting from English to Vietnamese but the app still displays English.
Here is my project directory:
enter image description here
main.dart
child: EasyLocalization(
          supportedLocales:  [Locale('en'), Locale('ar'), Locale('vi')],
          path: 'assets/translations',
          fallbackLocale: const Locale('en'),
          saveLocale: false,
          useOnlyLangCode: true,
          useFallbackTranslations: true,
          child: const MyApp())

Is it because the languageCode and countryCode are wrong?

Have you set assets in pubspec.yaml?
flutter:
assets:
- assets/translations/

Exactly how did you change language? Share all of the code.
